# Batch file is not being created

Tags: asp-classic, batch-file

I have code that is supposed to make a batch file on my c:\. It is supposed to create it on the onclientclick of my button. When I click on the button it doesn't create the file at the location. Am I missing code?

```
 function SubmitForm() {

    if (document.getElementById("hawbtxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the HAWB (B/L)!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("invrefpotxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the INV/REF/PO!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("hppartnumtxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the HP PART NUM!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("iecpartnumtxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the IEC PART NUM!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("qtytxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the QUANTITY!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("bulkstxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the BULKS!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("boxplttxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the BOX/PLT!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("rcvddatetxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the DATE!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("statustxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the STATUS!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("carriertxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the CARRIER!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("shippertxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the SHIPPER!");
        return false;

    }
    alert("called");

    var sText, s;
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

    if (!fso.FileExists("C:\\temp\\COO_BTO_Test.bat")) {
        s = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\temp\\COO_BTO_Test.bat", true);
        sText = "@echo off";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = ":Lbl";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "ECHO \"^XA^MD0^PRB^JVY^LL1760^LH%XL%,%YL%^FS   \">> COO.TXT";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "ECHO \"^FO66,08^BY2,2.0,32^BCN,N,N,N^SN%Sno0%,1,Y^FS   \">> COO.TXT";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "ECHO \"^FO66,48^AF,8,8^SN%Sno0%,1,Y^FS     \">> COO.TXT";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = ":END";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "ECHO \"^PQ1     \">> COO.TXT";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "ECHO \"^XZ     \">> COO.TXT";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "REM MODE COM1 9600"
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "REM TYPE COO.TXT > COM1"
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "TYPE COO.TXT > LPT1"
        s.WriteLine(sText);
        s.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you normally close a file after writing to it?

Comment: Yes, I added a close after it, thanks for reminding. Aside from that, even if I added a close, it does not create the file.

Comment: Are you sure you have permission to write in the root directory of C:\? Try using C:\temp

Comment: could it be permission issue?

Comment: It could be a permission issue, but I don't think I want to change any of those settings at the moment. I'll try a subfolder.

Comment: @Ian I tried the C:\temp but it still wouldn't create it..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows Vista or above, the default security settings will prevent you from creating a file on the root of `C:\`.

I changed your code to create the batch file in a subfolder, and it works great. Also, changing the security permissions on `C:\` works as well.

**EDIT:** the updated code will create the file in `C:\temp`

```
var sText, s;
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");


if (!fso.FileExists("COO_BTO_Test.bat")) {
    s = fso.CreateTextFile("COO_BTO_Test.bat", true);
    sText = "@echo off";
    s.WriteLine(sText);

    sText = ":Lbl";
    s.WriteLine(sText);

    sText = "ECHO \"^XA^MD0^PRB^JVY^LL1760^LH%XL%,%YL%^FS   \">> COO.TXT";
    s.WriteLine(sText);

    sText = "ECHO \"^FO66,08^BY2,2.0,32^BCN,N,N,N^SN%Sno0%,1,Y^FS   \">> COO.TXT";
    s.WriteLine(sText);

    sText = "ECHO \"^FO66,48^AF,8,8^SN%Sno0%,1,Y^FS     \">> COO.TXT";
    s.WriteLine(sText);

    sText = ":END";
    s.WriteLine(sText);

    sText = "ECHO \"^PQ1     \">> COO.TXT";
    s.WriteLine(sText);

    sText = "ECHO \"^XZ     \">> COO.TXT";
    s.WriteLine(sText);

    sText = "REM MODE COM1 9600"
    s.WriteLine(sText);

    sText = "REM TYPE COO.TXT > COM1"
    s.WriteLine(sText);

    sText = "TYPE COO.TXT > LPT1"
    s.WriteLine(sText);
}
```

Comment: Can you show me the code you have for creating it in a subfolder? Thanks

Comment: Hmm... I changed my code to look like that to put into the \temp folder but I didn't see a temp folder created in my c drive...

Comment: so when you run that code, it creates it in your c\temp folder? Because it still won't create it for me.. I also tried tweaking with the permissions and I don't have access to it.

Comment: you need to create the temp folder, do it for test

Comment: Hmm.. okay I created the temp folder in the c drive.. and ran it again. The COO_BTO_Test.bat does not show up in the folder.. suggestions?

Comment: do you compile it with jsc?

Comment: Cloud: Your edit is incorrect, it is an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

Comment: Well I'm using visual studios 2008. it supposed to run by a click of a button, and when the button is pushed it creates the file into the temp folder. if that's what you mean by how do I run it?

Comment: indeed - but please provide more details, or even upload the solution. What kind of project it is, etc.

Comment: Well it is  being ran on a asp.net website..basically its a website I created so a user can input data. when the button is pushed it makes the batch file. pushing the button also submits the information into a database. So I am using server and clientside code. all in 1 button. I will upload the full function. Everything works up until the point where it starts to create the batch..

Comment: OK, that's better info. Please try to use the updated code I edit now, and see if the file is created in the website folder.

Comment: Okay.. I just used your code, it does not create the file inside the website folder. (if what you mean by website folder is my folder where my website project is)

Comment: I'm sorry then - without the project itself, I don't think I have any other direction I can pursue. If you can, upload a zip of it.

Comment: Hmm.. well the project is kind of classified. So I don't think I can share it to you. It uses a database connection as well.. Thanks for your help though.